# Array or dictionary for saving a few instances?

Tags: ios, xcode, nsarray, nsdictionary

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.carMakes = [[NSArray alloc]
                     initWithObjects:@"Chevy",
                     @"BMW",
                     @"Toyota",
                     @"Volvo",
                     @"Smart", nil];

    self.carModels = [[NSArray alloc]
                      initWithObjects:@"Volt",
                      @"Mini",
                      @"Venza",
                      @"S60",
                      @"Fortwo", nil];

    self.carImages = [[NSArray alloc]
          initWithObjects:@"chevy_volt.jpg",
                      @"mini_clubman.jpg",
                      @"toyota_venza.jpg",
                      @"volvo_s60.jpg",
                      @"smart_fortwo.jpg", nil];
}
```

The above code is populated in a Table view. I want to give the user the option to choose a few cars and by doing so the name of the car, model and picture will be saved in another list. I don't know where I should save the data the user chooses and how.
I want to be able to show the user chosen car list on a TableView later on.

- I understand that if I want to keep the newly created list I'll need to convert the chosen info to a plist file or something like that but I'm not sure where to save the data before that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use array or dictionary for this. But a better approach is to create an array of model classes to hold these data. This is best suited for [MVC architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). For example, you can create a model class as `Car` which has properties, `NSString *make`, `NSString *model` and `UIImage *image` declared in it. If you want to populate the table view you need to create an array of these car model objects and use that in delegate methods to populate the cells. If you want to persist the data, you can either convert this into a dictionary form and then store it as a plist. For more details, check this [tutorial from ray wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1797/how-to-create-a-simple-iphone-app-tutorial-part-1)

A typical model object will look like,

```
@interface Car : NSObject {}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *make; 
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *model;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *image;
@end
```

Create array of model objects as,

```
Car *carObject = [[Car alloc] init];
carObject.make = @"Chevy";
//set other properties and create more objects
NSMutableArray *carList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[carList addObject:carObject]; //you can do this in a loop
```

While displaying you can just use `[carList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].make` etc..

or

```
Car *myCar = [carList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = myCar.model;
```

When the user chooses some cars, save those model objects into a separate array and save it as plist.

Comment: +1 for encouraging object-oriented design.  Never understood the frequent practice of using collection classes alone to represent the entire model layer.

Comment: @NSBum, Thanks.. :) This is the better approach and always easy to maintain. This kind of approach always helped me a lot in my projects. :)

Comment: "Model class as Car which has properties" Is that the same as `struct` in C ?

Comment: @MikaStern, It is not exactly same. But, yes it is a similar approach because it wraps all these properties in a single entity.  A model class can have convenience methods as well. For example if you want to manipulate some data based on some constraints, you can use some methods in model classes to do the same.

Comment: And there's no problem pushing a `car` `motorcycle` `cat` `human` in the same array later on? (In the end the user is going to have a list containing a few items that got nothing to do with the other and every item will have a few properties) is there such a thing an array of objects or is it just an array of ids maybe? (how do I define such an array?)

Comment: @MikaStern, That is fine. You can have any objects inside an array. When you are retrieving data from array just do a check as if([object isKindOfClass:[Car class]]) etc.. to verify whether it is a car, cat or human. **corrected method name*

Answer (score 2):

Suppose, you added the following cars into an array as follows.

```
[arraySelectedCars addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"BMW", @"Makes", @"Mini", @"Model", @"chevy_volt.jpg", @"Image", nil]];
[arraySelectedCars addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Toyota", @"Makes", @"Mini", @"Venza", @"toyota_venza.jpg", @"Image", nil]];
```

You can save them into NSUserDefaults, which reside into user's device till user delete apps or until you remove it.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:arraySelectedCars forKey:@"SelectedCars"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Later you can access the array and reload tableview as follows.

```
NSMutableArray *arraySelectedCars = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"SelectedCars"];
```